# bool for function in c language

Tags: c++, c

I would like to use bool in c language

first I see in C++

```
int maximum(int state, **bool choose**);
```

then

```
new_state = maximum(now_State, **true**);
```

I use boolean in C language by this:

```
#define true 1 
#define false 0 

typedef int boolean; 
boolean choose = false ;
```

but I dont know how to set on function like this(C++).

```
int maximum(int state, **bool choose**);

new_state = maximum(now_State, **true**);
```

Im foreigner. If you dont understand please tell me.

Comment: Both C++ and C have a built-in `bool` type. For C it's called `_Bool` but if you `#include <stdbool.h>` then you can use `bool`.

Comment: "but I dont know how to set on function like this(C++)." - I don't understand this. What do you mean by "set on function"?

Comment: for example 
int maximum(int state, bool choose);
bool dont have in C language. 
So, int maximum(int state, xxxxxx); How I change.

Comment: @SupaphonKamon There **is** a `bool` type in C.

Answer (score 6):

To use Boolean type C99 provides `<stdbool.h>` header. This header provides a macro `bool`. This header also contains the header `true` and `false` which stand for `1` and `0` respectively.

Comment: More to the point it is a proper boolean type. So something along the lines of `bool k = 2; if(k == true)` will work as expected

Comment: @doynax: well, `true` is a macro that expands to `1`, and `false` expands to `0`, so defining `typedef int bool` and `#define true 1` isn't _that_ different

Comment: in Visual C++ 2010 don't have <stdbool.h>

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Except that the code which *donyax* shows wouldn't work with `typedef int bool`.

Comment: @SupaphonKamon: That's because microsoft didn't support C99. That should've changed with VS2013, though

Comment: @Angew: True, I said it wasn't _that_ different, `if( !!(k) == true)` would work as expected, though, but I agree, it's not a clean approach

Comment: It is best to always test booleans as `if(k)` or `if(!k)` anyway, as it makes porting easier.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use enum:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { false, true } bool;

int main() {
    bool x = false;
    if(x != true)
        printf("x=%d\n",x);
}
```